# materialize modal popup auto initialize not working in vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, material-design, materialize

Materialize modal popup is working properly in onclick functions, but not working in mounted() or created()

```
     testingmodel:function(){ 
             $('#firstlogintour').modal('open'); 
        }

    mounted() { 
        this.testingmodel(); 
    },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have called the same function from VueJs updated event

```
updated() 
{ 
            this.testingmodel(); 
        },
```

** But you have to avoid the errors by using try catch on calling function

```
testingmodel:function(){ 
             $('#firstlogintour').modal('open'); 
        }
```

Vue Updated Scenario:

This function will call up to when the function or method loads without failure or any Error.

Comment: this happens because after mounted, your "#firstlogintour" element is not yet rendered. I don't know the reasons. But then, something else is initialized, and then, modal is available. You could achieve the same with `this.$nextTick(()=>this.testingmodel())`. But this is no good practice what you are doing in any case. Use watchers if you want to wait until it exists